How to run a postinstall script after the package.json file is written?
I currently use pnpm as package manager. I'm maintaining a monorepo (around 30 packages) that has a postinstall script at the monorepo root. This script will run a local custom script that should perform some consistency checks across all package.json files and tsconfig.json files (by reading the content of these files)
However, I observe that the script runs before the package.json file is updated.
If I have monorepo with, let's say, shared and app1 packages, here is what I observe:
cd /packages/app1
pnpm add @repo/shared --workspace


pnpm resolves the packages
it creates the node_modules structure
it runs the postinstall script of the monorepo root
it saves app1's package.json file with the new dependency.

Because the app1's package.json is not yet written when the postinstall script is ran, the script fails to detect the newly added packages.
Running the postinstall script manually solves the issue, but I'd like it to be automatic.
Is there anything I can do to execute my script after the package.json files are written? I'd prefer, if possible, to avoid any solution specific to pnpm.
